# Fix corrupted ZIP archive

Tags: file, header, zip, png, corrupt

I've got a corrupted zip archive with possibly corrupted files (an assortment of JPEG, GIF and PNG images) from my photography class (I'm the teacher).

From a quick look, it seems the student has purposely deleted the starting header of the ZIP as well as the starting headers of the image files. I can see the filenames and appropriate headers for a lot of the image files (this is for a photo project) but not all, so I think the student has deleted some of the starting bytes in order to make it unreadable and therefore un-gradable.

Quick repair using zip -F and zip -FF doesn't seem to work, and foremost fails for whatever reason...

Any help on fixing it? I just need to extract many of the images.

Comment: "the student has purposely deleted"? What about F or I if you want to be nice?

Comment: There are recognizable filenames though, such as "Composition.png," so I'm a bit curious to see as to what sort of images the student actually put in the zip